# Hyper-geometric Probability Distribution in item defect problem

Tags: distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

I was looking at the following example but couldn't get any solution...

> Items from a large lot are examined one by one until r items with a
>   rare manufacturing defect are found . The proportion of items with
>   this type of defect in the lot is known to be $'p'$. Let $X$ denote the
>   number of items needed to be examined. Derive the probability
>   distribution of $X$, and find $E\left (X \right )$.

I think this is related to hyper-geometric function but couldn't go further.

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. With questions that are routine book-work like this (this sort of question is explicitly solved in many textbooks), the treatment is somewhat different, as discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please read the link and modify your tags and the body of your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a hypergeometric distribution you should know both the population size (the "large lot") and the number of items examined ($X$).
You should use a negative binomial distribution, in [one of its formulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations): $X$ is the number of trials needed to get $r$ failures. The probability distribution is:
$$P(X=k)=\binom{k-1}{r-1}p^r(1-p)^{k-r}=\binom{k-1}{k-r}p^r(1-p)^{k-r}$$
where $k$ is the needed number of trials, $r$ the number of defective items, $k-r$ the number of good items.

If "defective item" is 1 and "good item" is 0, there are $n$ sequences like 10010001...001, 010001...101, i.e. sequences whose last digit is 1. The probability of a single sequence is $p^r(1-p)^{k-r}$, their number is the number of ways to choose $r-1$ "defective items" in $k-1$ trials (you don' count the last trial because it is always 1), so $n=\binom{k-1}{r-1}=\binom{k-1}{k-r}$.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: for me the word 'negative binomial' was enough to get the solution... and yeah I think instead of 'k-r' it should be 'r-1'

Comment: $\binom{n}{x}=\binom{n}{n-x}$, so $\binom{k-1}{r-1}=\binom{k-1}{(k-1)-(r-1)}=\binom{k-1}{k-r}$.